# How to disable underline variables in SublimeText?

Tags: typescript, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

When the cursor is on it which option is responsible to make underline such variables?

[image: sublimeText]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript plugin is to blame.
Can be disabled by adding

"Preference > Package Settings > TypeScript > Plugin Settings - User"

```
"typescript_highlight_occurrences": false
```

[The solution is here - Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/717)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (**don't** just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. *If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.*